# Pandas sort multi-index based on aggregation of a column if I were to consider one level of the index only

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

What is the fastest way of sorting the **city_sales_rep** Dataframe by the index 'city', mind that there is a multi-index in place. The order of the the index should be exactly the order in which the index is ordered in the second Dataframe **city**.

If there an easy and fast way to do this sorting in one go?

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,10,(10,3))) 
A.columns = ['city','sales_rep','sales']

city_sales_rep = A.groupby(['city','sales_rep']).sum()

city = A.groupby(['city'])['sales'].sum().sort_values()
```

Which leads in my example to **city_sales_rep**:

```
                sales
city sales_rep       
2    9              5
4    5              2
     7              5
     9              2
5    4              4
6    8              6
     9              9
7    2              2
     3              8
     6              4
```

And **city**

```
      sales
city       
5         4
2         5
4         9
7        14
6        15
```

While this seems to do what I want, it feels horribly inefficient:

```
city.join(city_sales_rep.reset_index(level=1),lsuffix='_x')[['sales_rep','sales']].reset_index().set_index(['city','sales_rep'])
```

P.S.: Edits to the title are welcome, I feel like its somewhat clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, but not sure about performance:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,10,(10,3))) 
A.columns = ['city','sales_rep','sales']

city_sales_rep = A.groupby(['city','sales_rep']).sum()
a = np.argsort(city_sales_rep.groupby(['city'])['sales'].transform('sum'))
city_sales_rep = city_sales_rep.iloc[a]
print (city_sales_rep)
                sales
city sales_rep       
8    2              7
7    2              8
6    2              9
9    6              4
     7              9
2    2              9
     4              9
     6              7
     7              5
```

Another soluton with new column:

```
city_sales_rep = A.groupby(['city','sales_rep']).sum()
city_sales_rep['new'] = city_sales_rep.groupby(['city'])['sales'].transform('sum')
city_sales_rep = city_sales_rep.sort_values('new')
print (city_sales_rep)
                sales  new
city sales_rep            
8    2              7    7
7    2              8    8
6    2              9    9
9    6              4   13
     7              9   13
2    2              9   30
     4              9   30
     6              7   30
     7              5   30
```

If possible duplicated `sum` for different `cities` and use pandas 0.23.0+ is possible sorting by level and column together, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels)

```
city_sales_rep = city_sales_rep.sort_values(['new','city'])
print (city_sales_rep)
                sales  new
city sales_rep            
8    2              7    7
7    2              8    8
6    2              9    9
9    6              4   13
     7              9   13
2    2              9   30
     4              9   30
     6              7   30
     7              5   30
```

Comment: seems kinda strange, that there would not cleaner solution to this problem, why are you using transform and not sum btw?

Comment: @FabianBosler - Because need Series with same size like `city_sales_rep` DataFrame.